# Create a link in a flash web banner

Tags: flash, hyperlink, banner-ads

Here is what I have a button with the same properties on up, over, down, hit. Then I go back to the timeline and I name the instance of the button the same as the button name. On the first frame of that button I add an 2.0 action with is this

```
on (release) {
    getURL("http://www.example.com/", "_blank");
}
```

When I run the syntax checker it says this.

```
1087: Syntax error: extra characters found after end of program.
```

There are no hidden character as i have deleted all spaces and then replaced them. It was copied from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding it on the first frame of the button add it in the frame of the actual time-line by selecting the button. (The action is a button action and not a frame action so it shouldn't be placed on a frame but on the button in the frame it resides in)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not express that right. It is on the first frame of the actual timeline, not the button frame.

Comment: Is it on the 'button actions' panel? (and not the frame actions themselves)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I did not have it set to Action 2 in the publishing menu. That fixed the problem.